# Deployment of spring boot modules in enterprise application:TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector is not assignable to interface ImportSelector

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, maven-plugin, multi-module, enterprise-architecture

I have a Maven project "Enterprise application" containing two modules. The first module is a maven standard java application that contains the domain, dao and business layer. The second module is a "java web application" maven. Here is the configuration set up so far:
- the standard java application module:
  Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MobilepaymentDao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(MobilepaymentDao.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
        <artifactId>mobilepayment</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobilepayment-dao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mobilepayment-dao</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JBehave -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

- the java web application module:
  Main Class

  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
          public class MobilepaymentApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                  SpringApplication.run(MobilepaymentApplication.class, args);
                  System.out.println("dans le main");

  ```
          }
          @Override
          protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
              return application.sources(applicationClass);
          }

          private static Class<MobilepaymentApplication> applicationClass = MobilepaymentApplication.class;
      }
  ```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
        <artifactId>mobilepayment</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobilepayment-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mobilepayment-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>mobilepayment-dao</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-xml</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

-- the enterprise application module (.ear)
pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>mobilepayment</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobilepayment-ear</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>mobilepayment-ear</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
       <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
            <artifactId>mobilepayment-dao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
            <artifactId>mobilepayment-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

-- the multi-modules maven project:
pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.nhit.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobilepayment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>mobilepayment</name>    

    <modules>
        <module>mobilepayment-dao</module>
        <module>mobilepayment-web</module>
        <module>mobilepayment-ear</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I deploy the enterprise application project from netbeans by clicking Run, I get this exception:

```
Deploying C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\mobilepayment-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mobilepayment-web" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mobilepayment-web: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$TransactionManagementConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportSelector
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$TransactionManagementConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportSelector
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$TransactionManagementConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportSelector
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportSelector"}}
```

Comment: I have the same error in my application. Did you find a solution? If so, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty old but I just came across the same issue and I found the solution by adding

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {TransactionAutoConfiguration.class}
```

But I applied that because I do not use any thing related to transactions in my application

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in last week. However, my setup was a bit different than yours.

I've packaged my new service in war and deployed to an old application (for policy reason, not technical reasons).

Anyhow, the solution of adding exclude value in annotation would not work in my case.
The workaround, however, is similar I have to put the excluding in configuration

```
 spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration
```

for more information regarding auto configuration please see, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html